# How to extend 3rd party components in Angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

I use  `datatable` from primeng and what to do if I want to add some features? 
This is typical template for using `datatable`:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars">
    <p-column>
      <template let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <button type="button" pButton
                icon="fa-bars"></button>
      </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>

  </p-dataTable>
```

Now, I want to implement row inline editing(not cell editing). And, I am thinking where to start. I can write directive but I don't know how to get access to row and dynamically apply directive.

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean by "row inline editing". Generally, you could implement your own directives which modifies the behavior of datatable rows. It could be complicated to write given that the component is 2000 lines

Comment: @laser this is example https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid/inline_row_editing